# updating form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

i'm  trying to update my form but nothing is updated,am i missing something in my code? , i want also the update form to have old values how can i do it, i tried to set the value="{{$records->id}}",value="{{$records->mb}}",value="{{$records->articleN}}"...  for the input files but didn't work

is my update method in my controller correct?
i can't tell what's the error!

this snippet code is from home.blade.php

```
  @foreach($records as $record)
            <tr>
            <td>{{ $record->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->mb }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->articleN }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->objet_dachat }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->designation }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->ninventaire }}</td>
                <td>{{ $record->date }}</td>
                <td class=" text-center">
                            <a class="m-r-15 text-muted update"  data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$record->id.'" data-target="#update">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: #2196f3"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="{{ url('delete'.$record->id) }}" onclick="return confirm('Voulez-vous le supprimé?')">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
    </div>
    </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <!-- Modal Update-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="update" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="update" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="update">Mise à jour</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form  id="update" action="{{ route('update_form') }}" method = "POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @csrf
                
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="e_id" name="id" value=""/>
            <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-4">Type</label>
    <div class="col-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="mb" id="e_mb" value="">
        <option value="marché">marché</option>
    <option value="Bon de commande">Bon de commande</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">N° d'article</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                
                    <input type="text"  name="articleN" id="e_articleN" value="">
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">Objet d'Achat</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                
                    <textarea name="objet_dachat" id="e_objet_dachat" value=""></textarea>
                </div>          
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">Désignation d'article</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                
                    <input type="text"  name="designation" id="e_designation" value="">
                </div>          
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">Quantité</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                
                    <input type="number"  name="quantity" id="e_quantity"  value="">
                </div>          
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">N° inventaire</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                
                <input type="text" name="ninventaire" id="e_ninventaire" value="">
            
                </div>          
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-form-label col-4">Date d'acquisition</label>
                <div class="col-8">
                <input type="date" name="date" id="e_date" value="">
            
                </div>          
            </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icofont icofont-eye-alt"></i>Fermer</button>
                            <button type="submit" id=""name="" class="btn btn-success  waves-light"><i class="icofont icofont-check-circled"></i>confirmer</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Modal Update-->

    {{-- script update --}}
    
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.update', function () {
    var _this = $(this).parents('tr');
    $('#e_id').val(_this.find('.id').text());
    $('#e_mb').val(_this.find('.mb').text());
    $('#e_articleN').val(_this.find('.articleN').text());
    $('#e_objet_dachat').val(_this.find('.objet_dachat').text());
    $('#e_designation').val(_this.find('.designation').text());
    $('#e_quantity').val(_this.find('.quantity').text());
    $('#e_ninventaire').val(_this.find('.ninventaire').text());
    $('#e_date').val(_this.find('.date').text());
});

    </script>

{{-- hide message js --}}
    <script>
        $('#insert').show();
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $('#insert').hide();
        },5000);

        $('#error').show();
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $('#error').hide();
        },5000);
        
    </script>      

@endsection
```

controller code

```
public function update(Request $request)
     {
         
         $update =[
              'id'     =>$request->id,
             'mb'      =>$request->mb,
             'articleN'    =>$request->articleN,
             'objet_dachat' =>$request->objet_dachat,
             'designation'=>$request->designation,
             'quantity'   =>$request->quantity,
             'ninventaire' =>$request->ninventaire,
             'date'   =>$request->date,
 
         ];
         Inventory::where('id',$request->id)->update($update);
         return redirect()->back()->with('insert','Mise à jour effectué avec succès!.');
     }
```

route

```
Route::post('/update', [App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'update'])->name('update_form');
```

Comment: So what you need to do is some debugging. The use of the `dd()` function will help you with that. In your `update` function, just `dd($request->all()` and see which data is posted. Then find your inventory record. Again, first dd() that record. Then do your update query. Check the sql of the update query, see if you missed anything